# Trying to add a column in Rstudio using casewhen based on the first word of a character in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

Little background, I am conducting a food choice experiment that includes different types of food such as steak, pizza, burgers, etc. I would like to find out which trial used which type of food so that I can conduct a GLM to investigate if the type of food had an impact of food choice.

The problem is that I have spelt these types of food differently in the data, either with a capitalised first letter or not (n00b error i know). Also, i'm trying to extract 2 possible words from the column "crossCheckExperiment" that contains many words.

Here is my dataset

```
    structure(list(session_id = c(53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047,
    53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047,
    53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047), project_id = c(495,
    495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495,
    495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495), exp_name = c("Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice", "Vegan label and food choice",
    "Vegan label and food choice"), exp_id = c(569, 569, 569, 569,
    569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569, 569,
    569, 569, 569), user_id = c(46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946,
    46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946,
    46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946), user_sex = c("male",
    "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male",
    "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male",
    "male", "male", "male"), user_status = c("guest", "guest", "guest",
    "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest",
    "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest",
    "guest", "guest", "guest"), user_age = c(21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21),
    trial_name = c("Steak_V_L_03_NV_NL_04", "Steak_V_L_01_NV_NL_02",
    "Chicken_V_NL_02_NV_L_01", "Sausage_V_L_01_NV_NL_02", "Curry_V_NL_06_NV_L_05",
    "Steak_NV_L_04_NV_NL_03", "Curry_V_NL_02_NV_L_01", "Pizza_V_NL_04_NV_L_03",
    "Pizza_V_L_05_NV_NL_06", "Steak_NV_L_02_NV_NL_01", "Burger_V_NL_04_NV_L_03",
    "Curry_NV_L_06_NV_NL_05", "Sausage_V_L_06_V_NL_05", "Steak_V_L_05_NV_NL_06",
    "Curry_V_L_01_NV_NL_02", "Burger_V_L_02_V_NL_01", "Steak_V_NL_02_NV_L_01",
    "Sausage_V_L_03_NV_NL_04", "Pizza_NV_L_06_NV_NL_05", "Pizza_NV_L_02_NV_NL_01"
    ), trial_n = c(29, 25, 50, 1, 46, 32, 38, 22, 69, 28, 14,
    48, 67, 33, 37, 11, 26, 5, 72, 20), order = c(1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
    ), dv = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 1), rt = c(2054, 2417, 2007, 3003, 2391, 3238, 3316,
    2371, 4109, 3052, 3274, 3658, 2824, 1888, 4198, 5815, 2651,
    6591, 5766, 3682), side = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1,
    2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), dt = structure(c(1607441861,
    1607441863, 1607441865, 1607441868, 1607441871, 1607441874,
    1607441877, 1607441880, 1607441884, 1607441887, 1607441890,
    1607441894, 1607441896, 1607441898, 1607441903, 1607441909,
    1607441911, 1607441918, 1607441924, 1607441927), class = c("POSIXct",
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), nreps = c(53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L,
    53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L,
    53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L,
    53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L,
    53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L,
    53047 = 144L, 53047 = 144L), subjBelief_left = c("vegan",
    "vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "no vegan", "vegan",
    "vegan", "vegan", "no vegan", "vegan", "no vegan", "vegan",
    "vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "no vegan",
    "no vegan"), subjBelief_right = c("no vegan", "no vegan",
    "no vegan", "vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan",
    "vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan",
    "vegan", "no vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan",
    "no vegan", "no vegan"), X1 = c("Vegan_steak_nolabel_3",
    "Vegan_steak_nolabel_1", "Vegan_chicken_nolabel_2", "Vegan_sausage_nolabel_1",
    "Vegan_curry_nolabel_6", "Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_4", "Vegan_curry_nolabel_2",
    "Vegan_pizza_nolabel_4", "Vegan_pizza_nolabel_5", "Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_2",
    "Vegan_burger_nolabel_4", "Nonvegan_curry_nolabel_6", "Vegan_sausage_nolabel_6",
    "Vegan_steak_nolabel_5", "Vegan_curry_nolabel_1", "Vegan_burger_nolabel_2",
    "Vegan_steak_nolabel_2", "Vegan_sausage_nolabel_3", "Nonvegan_pizza_nolabel_6",
    "Nonvegan_pizza_nolabel_2"), X2 = c("Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_4",
    "Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_2", "Nonvegan_chicken_nolabel_1",
    "Nonvegan_sausage_nolabel_2", "Nonvegan_curry_nolabel_5",
    "Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_3", "Nonvegan_curry_nolabel_1", "Nonvegan_pizza_nolabel_3",
    "Nonvegan_pizza_nolabel_6", "Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_1", "Nonvegan_burger_nolabel_3",
    "Nonvegan_curry_nolabel_5", "Vegan_sausage_nolabel_5", "Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_6",
    "Nonvegan_curry_nolabel_2", "Vegan_burger_nolabel_1", "Nonvegan_steak_nolabel_1",
    "Nonvegan_sausage_nolabel_4", "Nonvegan_pizza_nolabel_5",
    "Nonvegan_pizza_nolabel_1"), crossCheckExperiment = c("Steak_V_L_03_NV_NL_04",
    "Steak_V_L_01_NV_NL_02", "Chicken_V_NL_02_NV_L_01", "Sausage_V_L_01_NV_NL_02",
    "Curry_V_NL_06_NV_L_05", "Steak_NV_L_04_NV_NL_03", "Curry_V_NL_02_NV_L_01",
    "Pizza_V_NL_04_NV_L_03", "Pizza_V_L_05_NV_NL_06", "Steak_NV_L_02_NV_NL_01",
    "Burger_V_NL_04_NV_L_03", "Curry_NV_L_06_NV_NL_05", "Sausage_V_L_06_V_NL_05",
    "Steak_V_L_05_NV_NL_06", "Curry_V_L_01_NV_NL_02", "Burger_V_L_02_V_NL_01",
    "Steak_V_NL_02_NV_L_01", "Sausage_V_L_03_NV_NL_04", "Pizza_NV_L_06_NV_NL_05",
    "Pizza_NV_L_02_NV_NL_01"), checkSubjId = c(53047, 53047,
    53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047,
    53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047
    ), subjectVeganQuantification = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), left_food = c("V", "V",
    "V", "V", "V", "NV", "V", "V", "V", "NV", "V", "NV", "V",
    "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "NV", "NV"), left_label = c("L",
    "L", "NL", "L", "NL", "L", "NL", "NL", "L", "L", "NL", "L",
    "L", "L", "L", "L", "NL", "L", "L", "L"), right_food = c("NV",
    "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV",
    "NV", "V", "NV", "NV", "V", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV"), right_label = c("NL",
    "NL", "L", "NL", "L", "NL", "L", "L", "NL", "NL", "L", "NL",
    "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "L", "NL", "NL", "NL"), dv_inv = c(1,
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    appear_selected = c("no vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan", "vegan",
    "no vegan", "no vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "vegan", "no vegan",
    "no vegan", "no vegan", "vegan", "no vegan", "vegan", "vegan",
    "no vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan", "no vegan"), label_selected = c("NL",
    "NL", "L", "L", "L", "NL", "NL", "NL", "L", "NL", "L", "NL",
    "L", "NL", "NL", "NL", "L", "NL", "L", "L"), counter = c(1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    dv_recoded = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), cong = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), veg_cong = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), incong = c(0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    noveg_cong = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), control_cong = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), congVar = c("cong",
    "cong", "incong", "veg_cong", "incong", "noveg_cong", "incong",
    "veg_cong", "cong", "noveg_cong", "incong", "noveg_cong",
    "veg_cong", "cong", "veg_cong", "veg_cong", "incong", "cong",
    "noveg_cong", "noveg_cong"), cong2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), veg_cong2 = c(FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE), incong2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), noveg_cong2 = c(FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
    TRUE), fac = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L,
    1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("cong",
    "veg_cong", "incong", "noveg_cong"), class = "factor"), trialType = c(NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code I currently have

```
  my_data_filt <- mutate(Group =
                      case_when(if (my_data_filt) crossCheckExperiment == 'Steak', 'steak' ~ "steak", 
                                if (my_data_filt) crossCheckExperiment == 'Burger', 'burger' ~ "burger",
                                if (my_data_filt) crossCheckExperiment == 'Chicken', 'chicken' ~ "chicken",
                                if (my_data_filt) crossCheckExperiment == 'Pizza', 'pizza' ~ "pizza",
                                if (my_data_filt) crossCheckExperiment == 'Sausage', 'sausage' ~ "sausage",
                                if (my_data_filt) crossCheckExperiment == 'Curry', 'curry' ~ "sausage")
)
```

however, I keep getting this error

```
Error in if (my_data_filt) crossCheckExperiment == "Steak" : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code. The first is that you didn't include the data frame in the first argument for `mutate()`. The second is that `case_when()` is not being used properly. The third is that `==` only works when you are looking for something to be equal to one value. If you want it to be equal to one of several values, use the `%in%` operator.

```
mutate(my_data_filt, 
       Group = case_when(crossCheckExperiment %in% c('Steak', 'steak') ~ "steak", 
                         crossCheckExperiment %in% c('Burger', 'burger') ~ "burger",
                         etc....))
```

If the variable has the word of interest in it along with other stuff, the `str_detect()` function from `stringr` is helpful:

```
mutate(my_data_filt, 
           Group = case_when(str_detect(crossCheckExperiment, '(S|s)teak') ~ "steak", 
                             str_detect(crossCheckExperiment, '(B|b)urger') ~ "burger", 
                             etc....))
```

Comment: Hey Phil, thank you very much for the help I appreciate it! Unfortunately this returns NA in the that group column. I have included my code in my original question if that helps:)

Comment: This is because the `crossCheckExperiment` variable don't actually equal to "Steak", "Burger", etc. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much for your help Phil!! I really appreciate it:)